# Can Cloud Run access cloud sql to use unix socket in VPC direct egress?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-run, cloud-sql-proxy

I'm new about GCP network.

I recently use Direct VPC egress.
If I disable Direct VPC egress and use followed format DATABASE_URL

```
postgresql://user:password@localhost/db_name?host=/cloudsql/project_id:region:db_id
```

, it works, but if I enable VPC egress, it emit an error.

```
couldn't listen at "/tmp/cloudsql-proxy-tmp/connection_name ~ bind: invalid argument
```

I guess VPC subnet of VPC direct egress doesn't allow something egress ports or Internet Connection using IP, though I thought VPC network can use google private access.
I know cloud SQL network separated from project VPC network thus, we must use VPC peering, but I want to use public IP only with cloud SQL proxy if we can.
When we use subnetwork with Direct VPC egress, must we use private IP address of cloud SQL?

Comment: I am not sure Cloud Run direct VPC egress supports unix-socket connection to Cloud SQL. It is possible to use the CR direct-VPC along with Cloud SQL Auth Proxy to access private IP based Cloud SQL instance. This community thread had some decent deep-dive on this configuration. https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Serverless/Connection-Types-from-Cloud-Run-to-Managed-Cloud-SQL-What-is-the/m-p/663633

Comment: @GangChen is right. Cloud SQL connection on Cloud Run open a unix socket on a Cloud SQL instance with public IP. For that, you don't need a VPC access. If you want to use a Cloud SQL with only a private IP, you can't use the Cloud Run built in connector to Cloud SQL. You can use a side car proxy to open this unix socket on private IP with a VPC access. The trick here is to share the same volume between the side car (which open the socket) and the main container (which consume the socket)

Comment: Cloud Run and Cloud SQL are not part of your project's VPC. Connectors, etc are not transitive. That means traffic going into a VPC will not be routed outside that VPC. This will not work: Cloud Run -> VPC -> Cloud SQL Public IP. This will work:  Cloud Run -> VPC -> Cloud SQL Private IP. There is no benefit I can think of to trying to use Direct VPC Egress for Cloud SQL public addresses beyond the fact that it will not work.

Comment: I found this https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/serverless/announcing-direct-vpc-egress-for-cloud-run quite useful. In both direct VPC egress and VPC access connector's cases, the destination resources have internal IP addresses.

Comment: Thank you much information. In addition, I need to use VPC so that a cloud run service exposed to a public internet communicates with another cloud run in another project via shared VPC (I already know how to make it work). My main interest is whether or not we can use hybrid unix socket connection to sql via cloud sql proxy (or direct access) and VPC private access using Direct VPC and it's no problem to use private IP access if we have no choice to access to cloud sql's public IP.

Comment: You can use Unix sockets on Cloud Run. However, connectors are not transitive. That means if Cloud Run is sending traffic to VPC A, that traffic will not be routed to another Cloud Run in VPC B. This will not work: Cloud Run A -> VPC A -> VPC B -> Cloud Run B. Cloud SQL Proxy and Unix sockets are not related to a routing problem. They will not work if the traffic is blocked due to routing. Please see this [link](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc-peering#spec-general). Another common problem is that two VPC's cannot have overlapping addresses. Auto-mode VPCs use the same address block.

Comment: @guillaume blaquiere 
My project can use public IP SQL instance. In fact, though my postgres cloud sql has public and private IPs both, it can't be connected when I switch CR in vpc subnetwork cidr range using direct VPC egress. Because I expected that it can access to cloud SQL via cloud sql proxy when setting traffic to private ip range only ,  I'm confused for that behavior which may mean traffic via cloud sql proxy pass through vpc network. Is there any clues or way to find why cloud run can't access with public IP?

Comment: @JohnHanley Thank you, but I already achieved that by including their subnets in same shared VPC. My purpose is making one of container in it access to cloud sql (though using shared VPC, the sql instance and CR in same project) whether or not using private access or public access with unix socket (the latter is better for me)
Sorry for my shortage explanation.

Comment: I am confused about what you achieved and what you have a problem with. Please edit your question with details. When you have networking questions, you must be very specific. Generalized descriptions do not help.

Comment: https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Serverless/Connection-Types-from-Cloud-Run-to-Managed-Cloud-SQL-What-is-the/m-p/663633

My question is exact same in this thread. I achieved CR communications in shared VPC and not related to my question in this case though I needed to explain why I want to use cloud sql's public IP. Anyway it's a bit complicated problem and  I'll try more by myself at least, tcp access will work.

Comment: @JohnHanley

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77855349/can-cloud-run-access-cloud-sql-to-use-unix-socket-in-vpc-direct-egress#comment137256235_77855349

I read your comment carefully again. It may be right though I guess cloud run 
allow traffic to public internet out of private ip ranges (and it's true to some extent because my container can access to npm repository of internet) when configuring private ip range only setting, but cloud sql proxy connection may pass  traffic to VPC. So, we may have to make these request traffic to private IP. Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update(2024/02/03):

I found that cloud sql proxy restricts [108 chars](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/367008/why-is-socket-path-length-limited-to-a-hundred-chars) path with unix socket. And my DB socket path has more characters than it in the environment. You can access to cloud sql with public IP only when using PRIVATE_RANGES_ONLY traffic configuration and conform unix socket's restrictions.

From SQL Config:

[image]

From Cloud Run Config:

[image]

From Cloud Run Access Log:

[image]

You can also access using private IP as following followed by description.

Deprecated:

Further research, I conclude cloud run's default cloud-sql-proxy connection can't configure private-ip option of https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-proxy now.

This means the socket with proxy doesn't connect to private IP and should imply proxy using private google access to access identity aware proxy in VPC even if private_range_ip_only traffic config used.That is why unix socket connection is refused.If we want to use unix socket connection in VPC, only the way I thought is to run cloud sql proxy with private-ip option specified in sidecar as [guillaume blaquiere's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11372593/guillaume-blaquiere).

Current confident way to work around is private ip access as [@John Hanley describes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8016720/john-hanley).

The [article](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23221871/gang-chen) @gang-chen introduce is very helpful.